# GCDWebUploader.bundle causes code singing error (macOS)

Tags: carthage, gcdwebserver

When I try to submit a macOS app that has GCDWebServers 3.3.3 added via Carthage:

`github "swisspol/GCDWebServer" == 3.3.3`

I get the following error:

`Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. The binary at path [Better.app/Contents/Frameworks/GCDWebServers.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GCDWebUploader.bundle] contains an invalid signature.`

Thoughts?

Comment: There's no code whatsoever in `GCDWebUploader.bundle`, only resource files. Maybe something is wrong with Carthage. Try adding GCDWebServer by hand to your Xcode project.

Comment: Check if this commit solves the issue: https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer/commit/4231465c5847a567cceadd2c6f04e8bb9942ce9d

Comment: Add this one as well https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer/commit/9a97e44d97ab53402ac28c4017041f49c51da4da